# WindowIconfield and FocusLost don't work together

Tags: java, swing, jframe, listener, focuslistener

I need to set mouse at specific place when `JFrame` loses focus, but not when minimized. I use `Robot` to set mouse on position when frame loses focus (`FocusListener`) by starting timer which calls robot to move mouse. And when `WindowListener` sees that frame is minimized it stops timer (because it will not call robot anymore). All works fine except that robot is still working even when minimized. By gaining focus, robot stops and all goes fine, but not when minimized.

Here is a code example. Can anyone help me?

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

Clipboard clipboard;
Robot robot;
Timer tmr;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Test frame = new Test();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.timer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
}
void timer(){
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Test");
        StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("");
        clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
    }
};
Timer tmr = new Timer(500, actionListener);
tmr.start();
}

public Test() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {


addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
        robot=null;
        tmr.stop();
    }
});
addFocusListener(new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusLost(FocusEvent arg0) {
        try {
            robot=new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                robot.mouseMove(200, 200);
            }
        };
        tmr = new Timer(500, actionListener);
        tmr.start();
    }
    @Override
    public void focusGained(FocusEvent arg0) {
        robot=null;
        tmr.stop();
    }
});
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

setBounds(100, 100, 431, 286);
getContentPane().setLayout(null);

}
}
```

`FocusGained` (which works fine) and `windowIconfied` (which doesn't works fine) have same event handles, but don't work same...

**EDIT:**

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

Clipboard clipboard;
Robot robot;
Timer tmr;

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static void main(String[] args) {
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            Test frame = new Test();
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.timer();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
}
void timer(){
ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        System.out.println("Test");
        StringSelection selection = new StringSelection("");
        clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
        clipboard.setContents(selection, selection);
    }
};
Timer tmr = new Timer(500, actionListener);
tmr.start();
}

void startRobot(){
    try {
        robot = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            System.out.println("Robot");
            //robot.mouseMove(200, 200);
        }
    };
    tmr = new Timer(500, actionListener);
    tmr.start();
}

public Test() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {
    startRobot();
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
                tmr.stop();
            }

            @Override
            public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
                tmr.stop();
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
                tmr.stop();
            }

            @Override
            public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
                tmr.start();
            }
            @Override
            public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
                tmr.stop();
            }

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
                robot = null;
                tmr.stop();
            }

        });
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

setBounds(100, 100, 431, 286);
getContentPane().setLayout(null);

}
```

}

I just realized that when I minimize window using button it starts timer, and when minimize it by clicking on the taskbar program icon it stops fine. What is happening?

*SOLVED*:

I just added WindowStateListener and created field int state. When state changes I get it in field state. When Window deactivated, I ask if state is ICONFIED and then give instructions. Extremely simple but I tortured whit is all day.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Probably not MCVE (Minimal), but here is all I have...

Comment: At a glance it looks pretty minimal.  Though you might remove `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` and confirm it is ***not*** related to the system PLAF.

Comment: Could you use a WindowFocusListerner instead?

Comment: @MadProgrammer What is the difference? part with focus works good, part with minimization not. Or WindowFocusListerner does something else?

Comment: To my mind  it's about determining why focus was lost ;)

Comment: I changed focusListener to windowFocusListener, but nothing has changed. Where I make mistake?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to add `FocusListener` whereas you can achieve it by overriding other methods of `WindowListener`  where you can start the timer when window is opened/activated/Deiconified and stop the time when window is closing/closed/Iconified.

Sample code:

```
public TestWidnowMinimize() throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException, UnsupportedLookAndFeelException {

    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
            try {
                robot = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                    System.out.println("Robot");
                }
            };
            tmr = new Timer(500, actionListener);
            tmr.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
            tmr.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
            tmr.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
            tmr.stop();
        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
            robot = null;
            tmr.stop();
        }

    });
```

Comment: This is very nice, but there is two problems. First, robot needs to work only when window is without focus and not minimized, and sleep when has focus or minimized. You inverted things. When I change it in your code all works well except robot is working when minimized. I tried all combinations, but always works when minimized. What to do?

Comment: Robot will start once window is opened as per my code. or you can just start at when `frame.setVisible(true);` is called.

Comment: I think you don't understand me. Robot needs to work only when window is not active (without focus) and not minimized. In all other cases needs to sleep. I tried to start timer with robot at the beginning, and then when window opens timer stops. When deactivated, timer starts, when minimized timer stops and so on. But problem is when minimized it is still working.

Comment: But anyway, you will get +1, this is useful (but still incomplete).

Comment: can you post your actual code in your question itself as EDIT section to investigate it further because Robot stops when window is minimized. you are using two timers in your code, right?

Comment: Yes, I use one which always running and clears clipboard, and the other which runs robot. I edited question.

Comment: What are you doing? Why are you calling two methods stop and start at a time.

Comment: Because when not, it has bugs as it doesnt stops and starts well. I added it now, but it is same efect for minimization in both cases. I tried every single combination and nothing.

Comment: You don't need to call both the methods at a time. First read about these methods when they will be called. `windowIconified` method is called when window is minimized and `windowDeiconified` method is called when window is resumed from minimization.

Comment: Yes, ok. But it doesnt do what I need when minimized by pressing button. That is the problem. It starts even if it needs to stop...

Comment: Does someone knows why this doesn't work with minimize button and works when minimizing by the icon on taskbar?